# Array Within Array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can anyone help me in parsing below JSON Request using ng-repeat

I want to know how to use ng-repeat in HTML to get the **description of the troubles** in JSON

Using below code I am getting whole Object of trobles

**posts.json**

```
    {
  "persons": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "label": "checked",
        "type": "young"
      },
      "personType": "average",
      "troubles": [],
      "externalResourceLinks": []
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "label": "checked",
        "type": "aged"
      },
      "personType": "bad",
      "troubles": [
        {
          "name": "Rocky",
          "description": "Health problem",
          "criticality": false,
          "date": "2016-08-07T08:43:28+0000",
          "longDate": 1470559408519
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in HTML I am using

```
<tr>
<td class="features" ng-repeat="list in person">{{list.persontype}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="features" ng-repeat="list in person">{{list.troubles}}</td>
</tr>
```

Angular Function

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngTable"]);
app.controller('PostsCtrlAjax', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/posts.json'
        }).success(function(data) {
          $scope.post = data;
          persons = data['persons'];
                    $scope.person = persons;
        })
    }

]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of troubles so as an example based on your JSON this would work:

Your main module:

```
// app.js
(function() {

    angular.module('myApp', ["ngTable"]);

})();
```

Your controller:

```
// PostsCtrlAjax.js
(function() {

    angular.module('myApp').controller('PostsCtrlAjax', PostsCtrlAjax);

    PostsCtrlAjax.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {

        getPersons();

        function getPersons() {

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/posts.json'
            }).then(function(response) {

                $scope.post = response.data;

            }, function(errors) {

                // any error handling goes here

            });

        }

    }

})();
```

Your view:

```
<!-- your other html here -->

<tr>
    <td class="features" ng-repeat="person in post.persons">{{person.persontype}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="features" ng-repeat="person in post.persons">
        <p ng-repeat="trouble in person.troubles">{{trouble.description}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- the rest of your html here -->
```

I hope you don't mind me tidying up your code a bit to be a bit more semantic.

Comment: Can you please help in repeating through troubles using ng-repeat

Comment: How did you get on?

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for ur answer,, I am not able to get output using the above, Is there something missing

Comment: I have just updated my answer. Change `$scope.post = response` to `$scope.post = response.data;` in your controller.